# Can anyone understand the meaning of this seal? It"s taken from a calligraphy brushwork painting that I own

Tags: meaning, seal

[[image]] Painting consist of a total of three seals (YING;YANG;& OVAL)with a vertical inscription in kaishu script on my calligraphy ink brush painting.

Answer (score 1):

it would be “陶冶性靈”, roughly means “cultivating spirituality”

only the character “性” is in standard seal script, the other three are slightly distorted.

btw, the last one is actually “霝” (u+971d)